# How to use SQLDeveloper to connect to embedded Derby database

Tags: derby, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a project using derby and JPA. I can connect to the database fine within my application. I would like to connect to the embedded database with SQL Developer so I can easily browse/query the data in the database.

Here is the derby dependency I'm using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
    <version>10.7.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is the the connection info I'm using for JPA:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:fs-hash-database;create=true"/>
```

Using SQL Developer 3.2.09 I tried to add the driver in Tools > Preferences > Database > Third Party JDBC Drivers with the following entry:

```
C:\Users\axiopisty\.m2\repository\org\apache\derby\derby\10.7.1.1\derby-10.7.1.1.jar
```

But when I try to create a new connection, SQL Developer still only shows me the tabs for Oracle and Access. I can't get the JDBC tab for the 3rd party driver.

I think the problem is that the jar that I am adding as the 3rd party driver is the entire derby jar, not just the driver. Yet the driver is contained in the jar.

Does anyone know how to configure SQL Developer to use the org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver contained within derby-10.7.1.1.jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle SQL Developer can be manually configured to work with Derby using the drivers that come with the JDK as of Java 8.

**Step 1: In Oracle SQL Developer, include Derby related libraries.**

Oracle SQL Developer -> Tools -> Preferences -> Databases -> Third Party JDBC Drivers. I simply [Add Entry...] all libraries under C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\db\lib

**Step 2: Manually edit connections.xml**

Edit C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system4.1.2.20.64\o.jdeveloper.db.connection.12.2.1.0.42.151001.541\connections.xml

In this example I am using embedded Derby driver.

```
<Reference name="DerbyConn" className="oracle.jdeveloper.db.adapter.DatabaseProvider" xmlns="">
  <Factory className="oracle.jdevimpl.db.adapter.DatabaseProviderFactory1212"/>
  <RefAddresses>
     <StringRefAddr addrType="OracleConnectionType">
        <Contents>BASIC</Contents>
     </StringRefAddr>
     <StringRefAddr addrType="RaptorConnectionType">
        <Contents>Microsoft SQL Server</Contents>
     </StringRefAddr>
     <StringRefAddr addrType="customUrl">
        <Contents>jdbc:derby:firstdb;create=true</Contents>
     </StringRefAddr>
     <StringRefAddr addrType="driver">
        <Contents>org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver</Contents>
     </StringRefAddr>
     <StringRefAddr addrType="subtype">
        <Contents>SQLServer</Contents>
     </StringRefAddr>
     <StringRefAddr addrType="ConnName">
        <Contents>DerbyDB</Contents>
     </StringRefAddr>
  </RefAddresses>
```

Note:
1. The XML setting can be as plain as shown above.
2. customUrl is **jdbc:derby:firstdb;create=true**. This will initialize firstdb schema in C:\sqldeveloper\bin\firstdb. You can use **jdbc:derby:D:\\Project\\derbydb\\firstdb** to initialize schema to an absolute location.

Comment: Simply replace the above XML, **org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver** to **org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver** and **jdbc:derby:firstdb;create=true** to **jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/D:\\Project\\derbydb\\firstdb;create=true**, then SQLDeveloper can connect to network Derby server.

Comment: On mac OS X the connections file is located at `/Users/<username>/.sqldeveloper/system17.4.0.355.2349/o.jdeveloper.db.connection/connections.xml`

Comment: Just confirmed this works for SQL Developer version 17.4.0

Answer (score 7):

SQL Developer does not support Apache Derby. It only supports a very limited (and fixed) set of DBMS [as documented on the WebSite](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/featurelist-094691.html#con):

- Oracle (obviously)
- MySQL (obviously)
- SQL Server
- DB2
- MS Access
- Sybase
- Teradata

(All third party DBMS are listed as "read-only" on the website - whatever that means)

You will need a "real" general purpose JDBC client to use it against Derby like Squirrel, DbVisualizer or SQL Workbench/J.

Comment: Officially SQL Developer does not support Apache Derby. However, following @user3766196 answer, Derby connection can be manually added to SQL Developer.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work on sql developer 4.0.2.15 using the network driver by adding the driver files to the classpath and then editing the connections.xml file in  the directory AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system4.0.2.15.21\o.jdeveloper.db.connection.12.1.3.2.41.140418.1111

I did this by copying an sql server connection but it seems to work happily thinking it is an sql server database.

I added the following to the file :

```
     <Reference name="DATABASENAME" className="oracle.jdeveloper.db.adapter.DatabaseProvider" xmlns=""\>
      <Factory className="oracle.jdevimpl.db.adapter.DatabaseProviderFactory1212"/>
      <RefAddresses>
         <StringRefAddr addrType="port">
            <Contents>1527/DATABASENAME</Contents>
         </StringRefAddr>
         <StringRefAddr addrType="user">
            <Contents>USERNAME</Contents>
         </StringRefAddr>
         <StringRefAddr addrType="NoPasswordConnection">
            <Contents>TRUE</Contents>
         </StringRefAddr>
         <StringRefAddr addrType="subtype">
            <Contents>SQLServer</Contents>
         </StringRefAddr>
         <StringRefAddr addrType="RaptorConnectionType">
            <Contents>Microsoft SQL Server</Contents>
         </StringRefAddr>
         <StringRefAddr addrType="ConnName">
            <Contents>DATABASENAME</Contents>
         </StringRefAddr>
         <StringRefAddr addrType="hostname">
            <Contents>HOSTNAME</Contents>
         </StringRefAddr>
         <StringRefAddr addrType="customUrl">
            <Contents>JDBCURL</Contents>
         </StringRefAddr>
         <StringRefAddr addrType="SavePassword">
            <Contents>false</Contents>
         </StringRefAddr>
         <StringRefAddr addrType="driver">
            <Contents>org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</Contents>
         </StringRefAddr>
      </RefAddresses>
   </Reference>
```

You will have to configure it with the appropriate values for DATABASENAME, USERNAME, HOSTNAME and JDBCURL for your database.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

After many "bad URL format" and then some "null pointer exceptions" I finally succeeded to get this connection working! In my context not to an embedded DERBY Database, but to Derby [launched as a network server](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/adminguide/index.html). Here is the checklist:

- Using SQL developer version 20.x (earlier may do - not checked) with a JDK 8 (above 171 is required by SQL developer). The later contains javaDB that is historically the Apache DERBY 10 database.
- DERBY is started and listens to port 1527 (its default). Permissions must indeed allow localhost and/or remote connections according to your context. I strongly advise you to have your database ready, and then check connectivity with e.g. the native Derby [command line tool 'ij'](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/ij_intro.html). For instance, at the ij prompt:

> ```
> ij> connect 'jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/MyDB;user=MYUSER;password=abcd';
> ```

- ensure you add the Derby JDBC driver to SQL Developer > Tools > Preferences > Database > Third Party JDBC Drivers. Browse and add
  ***yourJDKpath*\db\lib\derbyclient.jar**; this single jar is sufficient.
- Create a new connection, just for having the entry created in the connection config file that we will have to manually edit. Ensure you give it the name you want, with the proper user and password. Fill-in any data for the other fields and save your connection. It can't work yet.
- Exit SQL developer and edit manually the connection meta data. In recent SQL developer versions, this file is in JSON, previous versions are XML, the attribute names are identical in both cases. The path is like:

> ```
> C:\Users\YourNAME\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system20.2.0.175.1842\o.jdeveloper.db.connection\connections.json
> ```

- Open the file and identify the connection you just created. Edit it to get something like:

  ```
       {
       "info": {
           "role": "",
           "SavePassword": "true",
           "OracleConnectionType": "BASIC",
           "RaptorConnectionType": "Microsoft SQL Server",
           "customUrl": "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/MyDB",
           "NoPasswordConnection": "TRUE",
           "password": "123456789PLVEC4wxu80ijhx5ALU4ZpRgo123456789=",
           "hostname": "localhost",
           "port": "1527",
           "subtype": "SQLServer",
           "ConnName": "DerbyDB",
           "driver": "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver",
           "IS_PROXY": "false",
           "OS_AUTHENTICATION": "false",
           "KERBEROS_AUTHENTICATION": "false",
           "user": "MYUSER"
       },
       "name": "local DERBY",
       "type": "jdbc"
   }
  ```
- Yes, you may have noted the references to "Microsoft SQL Server" as *RaptorConnectionType* and "SQLServer" as *subtype*. This is the magic trick. Of course, the client *driver* classpath is critical too, which is "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" for the Derby network mode client, as is the *connectionUrl*.
- Launch SQL Developer and open the connection that will appear under "SQLServer Connections"